# Control not working in a jQuery ColorBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a control which I want to appear using a Colorbox. It's pretty simple, a couple of dropdowns, a text box and a button to submit the content.

The control works fine, but when I use the Colorbox to display it I can't enter any text in the textbox and the submit button doesn't work.

The jQuery to call it is:

```
 $j(".colorBoxLink").click((function () {
                $j("div#popup").show()
                $j.colorbox({
                    inline: true,
                    href: "#popup",
                    modal: true,
                    scrolling: false,
                    onCleanup: function () {
                        $j("div#popup").hide();
                    }
                });
```

And the control is located in a div:

```
<div id='popup' style='display: none'>
     <uc1:TaskCreator runat="server" ID="TaskCreator" /> 
</div>
```

If I take out the display:none I can run the control fine from the page without popping it up.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29826/Color-Picker-ASP-NET-AJAX-Extender-Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that adding the ColorBox moves the form elements outside of the form tag.

Adding the line:

```
 $j("#colorbox, #cboxOverlay").appendTo('form:first');
```

Resolves the issue